# Expected identifier or '(' in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, error-handling

i just replaced the database file from desktop to project folder and then i got this error. this error is happening in sqlite  file which is blocked/uneditable so there is no chance of unintentional keyboard hit.. i have completed app,was just testing. i guess its an issue with simulator so i cleaned,erased applications from iPhone simulator folder but  nothing worked.. any quick advice? below is full error message

/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:147:12: Expected identifier or '('

other warnings along with this error are

Video_Search_Engine/favoriteListVC.m:9:9: In file included from Video_Search_Engine/Video_Search_Engine/../favoriteListVC.m:9:
Video_Search_Engine/favoriteListVC.h:10:9: In file included from /favoriteListVC.h:10:
Video_Search_Engine/DBmanager.h:10:9: In file included from Video_Search_Engine/DBmanager.h:10:
Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:49:24: Expanded from macro 'SQLITE_EXTERN'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the header files and implementation files that all parentheses are matched.

One way to check is to double-click the opening parentheses and see the corresponding closing parentheses. If it matches ok, then correct. Definitely, there is a missing parentheses. Check carefully.

Comment: +1 this is correct.  There is an error in a source/header file before `sqlite.h` is included.

Comment: i have 12 classes in project, in 4 files am including them as needed. i could not figure out where is problem before sqlite.h

Comment: search sqlite.h where it has been added.. and see before/after sqlite.h

Comment: you mean there is parenthesis missing in included file before sqlite.h? right? but if there would be an error like this then there must be shown on that file,, there is nothing like that .. is it an error of framework or database or file handling database?does sequence of  including files matters?

Comment: sequence of including files does not matter. i mean u have included sqlite.h somewhere. In that file, the parentheses does not match.

Comment: i have included sqlite just in one file and i checked thoroughly there is no parenthesis issue.. check this one error and three other information statements

Comment: Video_Search_Engine/favoriteListVC.m:9:9: In file included from Video_Search_Engine/Video_Search_Engine/../favoriteListVC.m:9: Video_Search_Engine/favoriteListVC.h:10:9: In file included from /favoriteListVC.h:10: Video_Search_Engine/DBmanager.h:10:9: In file included from Video_Search_Engine/DBmanager.h:10: Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:49:24: Expanded from macro 'SQLITE_EXTERN'